# Wget Mass Download slows down with with high numbers

Tags: wget

I have thousands of thousands basic text within an html page (no images) i wish to download. I have combined all the urls required in .txt files and the code

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

works fine until we get to high numbers where the filename is the same such as index.10000 it begins to slow down then it take 3 seconds per page instead of doing 10-30 per second

I could possibly be that it is working through the number sequence

Comment: It could possibly be that it's trying to hold it all in RAM, RAM is paging to HD, entire puter is slowing down… *[but that's just a guess]*

Comment: thats something i didn't think of Ive left it on for 3 days and done 150,000 pages. thanks for responding